# How to update a dictionary to add to a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have the dictionary

```
d = {
  "group1": [0],
  "group2": [3,7]
}
```

How can I update the list to add another value to it.

I thought

```
d.update({"group1": [4]})
```

would add the number 4 and that the new dictionary would be

```
{
  "group1": [0,4],
  "group2": [3,7]
}
```

but this is not the case when I try it.

Comment: What *does* your code do when you "try it"?

Answer (score 2):

```
d["group1"].append(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `.append()` method of the list.  You can access `d['group1']` and that is your list.

```
d['group1'].append(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to update a dictionary by appending key:values from another one, you can do it like this:

```
d = { "group1": [0],
      "group2": [3,7],
      "group3": [8]
    }
u = { "group1": [4],
      "group2": [5,9],
      "group4": [1,2]
    }

d = { g:d.get(g,[]) + u.get(g,[]) for g in {*d,*u} }

# {'group1': [0, 4], 'group4': [1, 2], 'group2': [3, 7, 5, 9], 'group3': [8]}
```